# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.theme.direction') when using MaterialTable

Tags: next.js, material-table, daisyui

I just installed Material table into my Next js 14 + Daisy UI project, when I try to use the simple implementation of the material table into my page I get this error `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.theme.direction')`

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Here's my page

```js
"use client";

import MaterialTable from "material-table";
import * as React from "react";

const CategoryPage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="h-screen p-6">
      <div style={{ maxWidth: "100%" }}>
        <MaterialTable
          
          columns={[
            { title: "Adı", field: "name" },
            { title: "Soyadı", field: "surname" },
            { title: "Doğum Yılı", field: "birthYear", type: "numeric" },
            {
              title: "Doğum Yeri",
              field: "birthCity",
              lookup: { 34: "İstanbul", 63: "Şanlıurfa" },
            },
          ]}
          data={[
            {
              name: "Mehmet",
              surname: "Baran",
              birthYear: 1987,
              birthCity: 63,
            },
          ]}
          title="Demo Title"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CategoryPage;
```

Comment: Things such as theming in React libraries (i.e. MUI) are provided using context providers. You are most likely missing this in your _app page / layout file.

Comment: Thank you very much, I managed to resolve the issue by adding a ThemeProvider in my rootLayout file.